# How to use custom password hashing algorithms when authenticating to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

What would it take to use a stronger password hashing algorithm than SCRAM-SHA256 when using password authentication to Postgres? For example, say we want to use Argon2 or PBKDF2-SHA256.

The official documentation only mentions plaintext, md5, and scram as options: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html

Is there any setting I missed or readily available method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'd have to hack PostgreSQL to do that.